# Anorm log statements before execution

Tags: scala, jdbc, anorm

Is there way to log Anorm statements before execution. Currently I'm logging statements via JDBC driver trick:

application.conf:

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://someDBServer/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true&logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger&profileSQL=true"
db.default.logStatements=true
```

But I would like to log statements before execution, for debugging and logging purposes. For example I have error in my sql syntax, I use Hickary CP (2.5.x Playframework)

Log output is not useful:

```
2017-01-23 16:37:01  application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 [INFO ] controllers.AppController  - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$executeUpdate$1.apply(Anorm.scala:163)
    at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$executeUpdate$1.apply(Anorm.scala:163)
```

Println doesnt help either:

```
  db.withConnection { implicit c =>
    def sql = SQL("delete from USER where (username = {username} or username = {org_jed }) and id = {id}").on(
      'username -> user.username,
      'org_jed -> user.org_jed,
      'id -> some.id
    )
    println("Statement: " + sql.preparedStatement(c))

    sql.executeUpdate()
  }
```

Comment: You can have a look at [Acolyte debug utility](http://acolyte.eu.org/scala/#debug-utility) (NB: Acolyte is used by Anorm for its tests)

Comment: I have tried it & it's pretty cool can it be used for logging ? I tested problematic SQL statement by copy-pasting in Acolyte enclosure. Is there way not to duplicate statement in test and in Controller ?

Comment: That's for debug purpose, you can change its printer and use a logger, buts that's not the initial purpose